# Deriving a list of time differences from a column in a dataset and appending the list as a new column

Tags: dataset, core-language, date-and-time

I know it's a beginner question, but I've struggled with it for some time now and can't find a solution.

I have a dataset consisting of timestamps, where I've managed to compute the time differences with the help of a for loop:

```
For[i = 1; t = 0, i < 3, i++,  
  t = 
    UnitConvert[
      DateDifference[
        DateObject[sessions5311[i, "datetimeaccess"]], 
        DateObject[sessions5311[i + 1, "datetimeaccess"]]], 
      "Minutes" ]; 
  Print[t]]

sessions5311 = sessions5311[All, Append[#, "Differences" -> t] &]
```

When I try to append it, only the last value of `t` is being inserted in the "Differences" column, but I would want to have each of the current values of the t variable during the computation there.

[image]

Your help is much appreciated :).

Comment: Better use `Table` instead of `For` + `Print`. `Print` is meant only for display, not for returning values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you did not give us your dataset to work with, I contrived this one for exposition purposes.

```
ds = 
  Dataset[
    {Association["a" -> 1, "b" -> "x", 
      "date" -> DateObject[{2019, 4, 14, 20, 14, 47.767113}, "Instant", Gregorian", -4.]], 
     Association["a" -> 2, "b" -> "y", 
       "date" -> DateObject[{2019, 4, 15, 20, 14, 47.767451}, "Instant", "Gregorian", -4.]], 
     Association["a" -> 3, "b" -> "z", 
       "date" -> DateObject[{2019, 4, 16, 20, 14, 47.767678}, "Instant", "Gregorian", -4.]], 
     Association["a" -> 4, "b" -> "x", 
       "date" -> DateObject[{2019, 4, 17, 20, 14, 47.7679}, "Instant", "Gregorian", -4.]], 
     Association["a" -> 5, "b" -> "y", 
       "date" -> DateObject[{2019, 4, 18, 20, 14, 47.768123}, "Instant", "Gregorian", -4.]], 
     Association["a" -> 6, "b" -> "z", 
       "date" -> DateObject[{2019, 4, 19, 20, 14, 47.768346}, "Instant", "Gregorian", -4.]]}];
```

With this dataset, I can add a column of date differences given in minutes starting with the following code.

```
rows = Length @ ds;
dates = ds[All , "date"] // Normal
diffs = 
  Association["differce" -> #] & /@
    Prepend[
      Table[DateDifference[dates[[i]], dates[[i + 1]], "Minutes"], {i, rows - 1}],
      Quantity[0., "Minutes"]]
```

Evaluation gives a list of differences expressed as associations.

> ```
> {<|"difference" -> Quantity[0., "Minutes"]|>, 
>  <|"difference" -> Quantity[1440., "Minutes"]|>, 
>  <|"difference" -> Quantity[1440., "Minutes"]|>, 
>  <|"difference" -> Quantity[1440., "Minutes"]|>, 
>  <|"difference" -> Quantity[1440., "Minutes"]|>, 
>  <|"difference" -> Quantity[1440., "Minutes"]|>}
> ```

The list can be appended to `ds` as new column having the key "difference" with the following one-liner.

```
ds = Join @@@ Transpose @ {ds // Normal, diffs} // Dataset
```

[image: ds]

Comment: `DateDifference` accepts a unit as an optional third argument, so there is no need for the `UnitConvert`.

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi. Good tip. I have updated my code to use it.

Comment: Another way to generate the successive differences `ds[All, "date"][
  Differences][All, <|"Difference" -> UnitConvert[#, "Minutes"]|> &]`

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi. It might be better if you would write up your alternative method as another answer. It would be more accessible that way.

Comment: Thank you both very much for your help, it worked now.

Comment: @Lucy. I'm glad you find my answer useful. Please consider accepting it. You can do that by clicking on the check mark that appears on the left of the answer below the down arrow.